# jQuery appentTo and reset/reorder position function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending into a "div" several "img" tags, using appendTo() which seems to be working great. now what if I want to remove an image and reorder them? To make my self more clear, I am keeping the image divs in an array. When I delete an element from that array, I also want  the "visual" images to be reordered. 
So I have this:

```
[img_1] [img_2] [img_3] -> in a div
```

now if I delete "image div" 2 I want to get this:

```
[img_1] [img_3] -> in a div
```

and NOT this:

```
[img_1]       [img_3] -> in a div
```

Comment: show us how you do the adding/removing .. (*html & js*)

Comment: And if you delete an `<img>` what **actual** html do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with images in it and you want to both remove an image from the array and remove it from the DOM, you can create a function like this to do both operations for you:

```
var imgArray = [img1, img2, img3];

function removeImage(array, index) {
    array[index].parentNode.removeChild(imgArray[index]);   // remove from DOM
    array.splice(index, 1);                                 // remove from array
}

removeImage(imgArray, 1);
```

The first line in that function removes the second element in the array from the DOM.

The second line in that function removes the second element from the array.

---

FYI, you may want to know that jQuery makes it so easy to get a list of images that are in any div that it is often the case that you don't need to keep a parallel array of images in javascript.  If you want the list of images in a div, you can just fetch it at any time using jQuery and the right selector.

For example, if you had this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="xxx">
    <img src="yyy">
    <img src="zzz">    
</div>
```

You could get a list of the images at any time with this jQuery:

```
$("#container img")
```

And, you could remove the second image with this:

```
$("#container img").eq(1).remove();
```

Comment: when you say "remove it from the DOM" will the images automatically rearrange or will I have blank spots?

Comment: @TestTest - unless you've done something unusual with absolute positioning on your images, the browser will reposition the other images when you remove one from the DOM.  If you show us your HTML/CSS we could answer more specifically.